# Detail in Radon Nikodym theorem by Bartle

Tags: measure-theory

First, I will give a formulation of Radon Nikodym theorem.

*Let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be $\sigma$- finite measures defined on X and suppose that $\lambda$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$. Then there exists a non negative measurable function such that $\lambda(E)=\int_{E}f\,d\mu$.*

Since the proof of Radon Nikodym theorem is very demanding and long, I will try to formulate (in a sense of lemma) just part of it which is problematic to me.

My question is:

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be measurable space, such that $\mu(X)<\infty$. Let $f\in L^{1}(\mu)$ (that is $\int_{X}|f| d\mu <\infty$). Let $|\int_{X} f d\mu|\leq c$ , where $c>0$ is constant. 
Does it mean that then $|\int_{X} f d\mu|\leq \int_{X}|f|d\mu \leq c$?

I know that for $f \in L^{1}(\mu)$ holds $|\int_{X} f d\mu|\leq \int_{X}|f|d\mu$, but I can not see if above given inequality holds. Maybe I am missing something obvious. Any help would be good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inequality is false.  Consider $X = [0,1]$, $f(x) = k(2x-1)$ for large values of $k$ and small values of $c$.

Of course if $f \ge 0$ then you have equality.